# Order of a group $G$

Tags: group-theory

A finite group contains an element $x$ of order $10$ and also an element $y$ of order $6$. What can be said about the order of $G$ ?

By Langrange's theorem, we establish a corollary stating that the order of an element of a finite group divides the order of the group.

Therefore: $10|\;\; |G|$ and $6|\;\; |G| $

Does that imply that $|G|=2$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No, as 2 is neither a multiple of 10, nor of 6 :)

Comment: $|G|$ a multiple of 10 and a multiple of 6 so it is a multiple of ....?

Comment: Ah ! Sorry. Yes the only thing we can deduce is the fact that |G|=10k and |G|=6p 

ie |G| is at least 30

Comment: @Carpediem be careful how you phrase it, we do not only know "it is at least 30" (unless you've made a habit of always ordering numbers by divisibility), we know it is *divisible by 30*

Comment: @JHance You are right. Or I could write: 30 | |G| no ?

Comment: @Carpediem Precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that $6 | \left| G \right|$ means $\left|G\right|$ is *divisible by* 6.  So the combination of the facts means that $\left|G\right|$ is divisible by both $6$ and $10$.  This requires that $\left| G \right|$ is divisible by 30, the least common multiple of $6$ and $10$.